Issue with updating API context object in react native using typescript
I'm new to using hooks in react native (typescript) and I'm trying to setup my app so that it keeps the state of the user throughout using the API Context (useContext) and I want to update the user object in the children (consumer) components.
Here's my _layout.tsx:
function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | undefined>({
    __typename: "User",
    id: 'testUser',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    watchlist: null,
    createdAt: 'now',
    updatedAt: 'now',
    _version: 0,
    _lastChangedAt: 0
  });

  const providerValue = { user, setUser };

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DarkTheme}>
          <UserContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
            <Stack>
              <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="onboarding/onboarding" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="components/StockDetails" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
            </Stack>
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

And here's my UserContext class:
import { User } from "@/userApiCode";
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext<User | undefined>({
    __typename: "User",
    id: '',
    email: '',
    watchlist: null,
    createdAt: '',
    updatedAt: '',
    _version: 0,
    _deleted: null,
    _lastChangedAt: 0,
    owner: null
    });

export function useUserContext() {
    const user = useContext(UserContext);
    if(user === undefined) {
        throw new Error("User is undefined for creating userContext.");
    }
    return user;
}

I am trying to call it in my Dashboard (child) component which uses useContext to take the value from the UserContext.Provider and update that data with a graphQL API call. I want this updated value to be reflected every time the context is called:
  // Get our user
  const {user, setUser} = useUserContext();

  let getUserResult = await client.graphql({
    query: getUser,
    variables: {
      id: uid
    }
  });

  if(getUserResult.data.getUser != null){
    setUser(getUserResult.data.getUser);
  }

The issue is I'm getting a couple of errors:
1 - In my _layout.tsx,  error: Type '{ user: User | undefined; setUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<User | undefined>>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': __typename, id, email, createdAt, and 3 more.ts(2740) index.d.ts(366, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<User | undefined>'
2 - In my Dashboard.tsx error: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'User'. Property 'setUser' does not exist on type 'User'.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
